# Cordova plugin multiple classes

Tags: cordova-plugins

I first created a simple cordova plugin that containt one single java class *(`Hello.java` for instance)* that shows alert : everything works fine.

Now i want to add more features to my plugin, i added another java class *(`Alert.java`)* and in my `Hello.java` i want to use `Alert.java` methods, i instantiated `Alert.java` class but after building, it shows error as it doesn't recognize it : `Alert myAlert = new Alert();`

Thanks in advance for clearing what i'm doing wrong *(i only know basics in Java and completly new to cordova)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply putting the two files in the same package, initializing the class would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put the java files in plugin.xml